# How do I install RODBC so that is uses unixODBC?

Tags: sql-server, r, freetds, rodbc, unixodbc

After installing and configuring FreeTDS and unixODBC and confirming they are working correctly, I am trying to configure RODBC.  However, I am getting the following results when attempting to view the ODBC data sources in the R console.

```
> odbcDataSources()
named character(0)
```

If I attempt to use the FreeTDS driver I get the following results.

```
>odbcDriverConnect("driver={FreeTDS};server=xx.xx.xx.xx;port=1433;database=XXXX_Analysis;trusted_connection=true;UID=********;PWD=********") :
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM003, code 0, message [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded
```

Based on the error, it looks like RODBC is trying to use iODBC instead of unixODBC.  I am not sure how to configure RODBC to use unixODBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to specify the odbc manager to the package's configure script, like this

```r
install.packages("RODBC", 
 type = "source", 
 INSTALL_opts="--configure-args='--with-odbc-manager=odbc'"
)
```

`--with-odbc-manager=odbc` indicates you want to use unixODBC
`--with-odbc-manager=iodbc` indicates you want to use iODBC

Comment: Thank you Jim. This is the right way to install ROBC from sources linking to unixODBC.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue after configuring unixODBC on Mac OS 10.13.3 High Sierra. I tried configuring my .Renviron to set an R-specific environment variable for ODBCINI, but RODBC still wouldn't list my data source names (DSNs). Additionally, I couldn't get it to find the driver specified in ODBCinst.ini or even get a connection string working with RODBC::ODBCDriverConnect(), despite being able to connect with isql.

What ended up working was simply:

```
remove.packages('RODBC')
install.packages('RODBC', type="source")
```

It seems if you install RODBC from source on mac, it picks up on the odbc.ini file and odbcinst.ini file correctly.

Thanks to this post's subtle comment for unlocking the key:
http://eriqande.github.io/2014/12/19/setting-up-rodbc.html

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the default RODBC package install won't work with unixODBC.  Here is a process for recompiling and installing RODBC.

1. Remove current generic RODBC package via the R console.

   ```
   >remove.packages("RODBC")
   Removing package from ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   ```
2. Download the source for RODBC.

   > https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/RODBC_1.3-15.tar.gz
3. Set the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location where your unixODBC library is located.  I used homebrew to install unixODBC so my my library is located in /usr/local/lib.

   `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`
4. Now reinstall RODB so it picks up the new library location.

   `R CMD INSTALL /Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/RODBC_1.3-15.tar.gz`

There is quite a bit of output but look towards the end and you should see something like this.

```
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o RODBC.so RODBC.o -lodbc -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
    installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/RODBC/libs
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices
    ** installing vignettes
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    * DONE (RODBC)
```

Notice the `-L/usr/local/lib` indicating the library location was picked up.

Now you should be able to see your ODBC connections provided by unixODBC. Back in the restarted R console you can type the following to verify RODBC is using unixODBC.

```
> library("RODBC")
> odbcDataSources()
      MYMSSQL1        MYMSSQL XXXXXXXXX_C_DB  XXXXXXXX-SQL1 
     "FreeTDS"      "FreeTDS"      "FreeTDS"      "FreeTDS"
```

Thanks to [hiltmon](https://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/09/18/setup-odbc-for-r-on-os-x/) for helping put me on the right track.